# tidytext -- how to do commonality and comparsion word clouds

Tags: r, tidyverse, word-cloud, tidytext

Let me start with the following and fully working code from [Introduction to tidytext @ CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tidytext.html)

```
library(janeaustenr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

original_books <- austen_books() %>%
  group_by(book) %>%
  mutate(linenumber = row_number(),
         chapter = cumsum(str_detect(text, regex("^chapter [\\divxlc]",
                                                 ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>%
  ungroup()

original_books

library(tidytext)
tidy_books <- original_books %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)

tidy_books

data("stop_words")
cleaned_books <- tidy_books %>%
  anti_join(stop_words)
```

All good so far.  I have a tibble with six Jane Austen novels, with the standard junk words removed.

```
unique(cleaned_books$book)
```

Which gets me: *Sense & Sensibility, Pride & Prejudice,   Mansfield Park,      Emma, Northanger Abbey,   Persuasion*.

So if I want to do a standard TF word cloud of all six, no problem.  Just like this (color added):

```
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
dark2 <- brewer.pal(8, "Dark2")

cleaned_books %>%
  count(word) %>%
  with(wordcloud(word, n, color = dark2, max.words = 100))
```

Works beautifully.  But how do I then do a **commonality.cloud()** with all six novels, and a **comparison.cloud()** with the same?

All the data I need is in **cleaned_books** -- but I can't figure out how to reshape it.  Your help appreciated!

### Got it.  Thanks.

Will leave up in case anyone else has a similar issue.

The above code &

```
set1 <- brewer.pal(8, "Set1") ## a second color just for other cloud type

library(reshape2)

# title size and scale optional, obviously
cleaned_books %>%
   group_by(book) %>%
   count(word) %>%
   acast(word ~ book, value.var = "n", fill = 0) %>%
   comparison.cloud(color = dark2, title.size = 1,  scale = c(3,  0.3), random.order = FALSE, max.words = 100)


cleaned_books %>%
   group_by(book) %>%
   count(word) %>%
   acast(word ~ book, value.var = "n", fill = 0) %>%
   commonality.cloud(color = set1, title.size = 1, scale = c(3,  0.3), random.order = FALSE,  max.words = 100)
```

That worked out nicely.

Comment: In the link you posted here, there is an example how to create a comparison plot from this data ...

Comment: Nope!  That is a comparison using sentiment analysis.  It does NOT compare the individual novels.

Answer (score 2):

Got it.  Thanks.  Run the above code. Then

```
set1 <- brewer.pal(8, "Set1") ## a second color just for other cloud type
library(reshape2)
```

Color is optional.  reshape2 essential.  Then just group by book, and go.

```
cleaned_books %>%
   group_by(book) %>%
   count(word) %>%
   acast(word ~ book, value.var = "n", fill = 0) %>%
   comparison.cloud(color = dark2, title.size = 1, scale = c(3,  0.3), random.order = FALSE,  max.words = 100)

cleaned_books %>%
   group_by(book) %>%
   count(word) %>%
   acast(word ~ book, value.var = "n", fill = 0) %>%
   commonality.cloud(color = set1, title.size = 1, scale = c(3,  0.3), random.order = FALSE,  max.words = 100)
```

All good!